# Pandas - drop_duplicates with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataset where I want to remove duplicates based on some conditions.

For example, say I have a table as

```
ID  date    group
3001    2010    DCM
3001    2012    NII
3001    2012    DCM
```

I wanna say look into ID column
for the similar IDs, if two dates were similar
keep the row that group is NII

so it would become

```
ID  date    group
3001    2010    DCM
3001    2012    NII
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `iloc` and `argsort` on a boolean array.  Make sure to sort with `mergesort` to ensure a non-volatile sort.

```
df.iloc[df.group.ne('NII').argsort(kind='mergesort')].drop_duplicates(['ID', 'date'])

     ID  date group
1  3001  2012   NII
0  3001  2010   DCM
```

This will ensure that within groups of `['ID', 'date']` pairs, rows with `'NII'` always come first.

Answer (score 11):

Leverage `duplicated` here:

```
df[~df.duplicated(['ID', 'date'], keep=False) | df['group'].eq('NII')]

     ID  date group
0  3001  2010   DCM
1  3001  2012   NII
```

Answer (score 3):

Change to `Categorical`, then `sort_values` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df['group']=pd.Categorical(df['group'], ["NII", "DCM"])
df.sort_values('group').drop_duplicates(['ID', 'date'])
     ID  date group
1  3001  2012   NII
0  3001  2010   DCM
```

If you have more than 2 , replace `["NII", "DCM"]` with follwing

```
["NII"]+df.group.loc[lambda x : x!='NII'].unique().tolist()
['NII', 'DCM']
```

Comment: I would recommend extending this to handle more than 2 categories.

Answer (score 2):

You can try sorting on `group`, it will have `DCM` value first (*ascending by default*), then using `subset` and `keep` option in `drop_duplicates` method :

```
df.sort_values('group').drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','date'], keep='last')
```